# Proving some functor is adjoint to another. What to do with naturality condition?

Tags: category-theory, proof-writing, proof-explanation, adjoint-functors

Whenever I want to prove that some functor is (left/right) adjoint to another, I (mostly using hom-set definition) go on smoothly to prove the "isomorphism of the corresponding hom-sets", until it turns to prove the *naturality* condition: It really sucks! I can't move anymore.

For example, in the case of $(-)\times A \dashv (-)^A$, where $(-)\times A , (-)^A$ are functors $\mathscr C \to \mathscr C $, I can easily confirm that the bijection  $Hom_{\mathscr C}(X \times A,Y) \cong Hom_{\mathscr C}(X,Y^A)$ holds for any $X,Y \in \mathscr C$ (by the way this hold by the definition of an exponential, or in general, by its universal mapping property). What I can't prove is that this is *natural*.

Now I'm wondering if this is easier than I think, which it seems so, as in no reference I see people struggling with the naturality condition, they ignore it so that it's something quite obvious.

Any help will be thanked!

Comment: Is $\Bbb C$ a general category?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick it's a category with binary products and exponentials.

Comment: Isn't exponential object defined as right adjoint to product functor? There is nothing to prove in that case, except if you have some particular category you want to prove that has exponential objects.

Comment: Unless you make strange choices those things tend to be natural. In case of exponential in the category of sets you map the function $f((x,y))$ to $(f(x))(y)$, so being natural means that $f( (g(x),h(y) ))$ is mapped to $(f(g(x)))(h(y))$. If the constructions are universal you get it for free. You could look at the different characterizations of adjoints and ask yourself how naturally goes in there. Maybe you can also look at monads or the adjoint functor theorem(there you can see what you need for the existence of adjoints). (But both require some familiarity with the basic notions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's often easier to use the "initial object in a comma category" definition of the adjoint, because it's much more concrete. Given $A \in \mathcal{C}$, you must find $i_A : A \to GFA$ such that for any $f: A \to GX$, there is a unique $g: FA \to X$ such that $Gg: GFA \to GX$ has $Gg \circ i_A = f$.

Comment: This one helped more than others.Thanks. Just for the record, this lecture notes also helped me:
https://www.dpmms.cam.ac.uk/~jg352/pdf/CTFurtherExamples2.pdf

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean naturality in $A$ in this case, as naturality in $X$ and $Y$ is either true by definition or usually comes for free for the style you are using.  The basic result that you need, which you can prove once then forget, is called parameterized representability and is covered in [Glynn Winskel's and Mario Cáccamo's lecture notes](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~gw104/catnotes.ps).  That's a PostScript file which is a bit awkward, see also Cáccamo's thesis, [A Formal Calculus for Categories](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=19392E1E8BE25D32D70B1F09F9FF3B16?doi=10.1.1.1.7460&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

The statement is: Say you have a bifunctor $B : \mathcal{C}\times\mathcal{D^{op}}\to\mathbf{Set}$ such that for each object $C$ in $\mathcal{C}$ you have a representation of $B(C,-)$, i.e. you have a function from objects of $\mathcal{C}$ to representing objects in $D$, say $F : \text{Ob}(\mathcal{C}) \to \text{Ob}(\mathcal{D})$ and a natural ismorphism $\tau_C : B(C,-)\cong\text{Hom}(-,F(C))$ for each $C$ **not** a priori natural in $C$.  Then this *uniquely* extends to a functor $F : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ which *does* make $\tau$ natural in $C$.  Prove this.

Applying it to your example, set $B_Y(A,X) = \text{Hom}(X\times A,Y)$ which is represented for each $A$ by $B_Y(A,-)\cong\text{Hom}(-,Y^A)$.  Therefore, $Y^A$ is functorial in $A$ and the isomorphisms are natural in $A$.

The upshot is as long as everything is functorial, you never need to worry about naturality in "parameters"; it comes for free.  This was important in Cáccamo's thesis where he defined a formal calculus where you really wouldn't want to have side-conditions everywhere to check naturality.

Comment: No indeed I don't get exactly it why "... naturality in $X$ and $Y$ is either true by definition or usually comes for free for the style you are using" holds.

Comment: I mean, can you do it explicitly for the case i'm concerned with, for example?

Comment: @Amir.HKiani People are confused, I think, about what you think an exponential is. The simplest definition is that an exponential is the right adjoint to the product, which includes naturality in $X$ and $Y$ automatically, as claimed.

Comment: @Amir.HKiani What Kevin said. What are you using to define to the isomorphism?  Or did you mean in concrete cases, e.g. $\mathbf{Set}$? Note, the above can still be a bit helpful, albeit *much* less so, because we can choose $B_A(Y,X) = \text{Hom}(X\times A, Y)$, and then it says you only need the object part of $Y^A$ and to show representability "point-wise" from which you will automatically get a functor and a natural isomorphism, i.e. adjunction. In other words, if you show naturality in $X$, naturality in $Y$ would follow. This reduces the complexity and work required a bit.

Comment: Sorry for late answer! I'm using the definition of an exponential independently from the notion of adjointness. Here is my resource (Awodey): 
https://books.google.com/books?id=IK_sIDI2TCwC&pg=PA107&lpg=PA107&dq=awodey+-+now+the+property+just+stated+of+the+evaluation&source=bl&ots=5W7sX5zjgo&sig=tZljdNWNpDWg0tg2YwBO3HSLmIQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj75bLuy4vMAhXDWRQKHezVC0cQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=awodey%20-%20now%20the%20property%20just%20stated%20of%20the%20evaluation&f=false

Comment: @Amir.HKiani Okay, that definition is *not* equivalent to $(-)\times B \dashv (-)^B$ because you may not even have another object $D$ such that a $D^B$ exists.  It is equivalent to the functor $\text{Hom}((-)\times B,C)$ being represented by $C^B$. You can't apply the theorem I referenced to this to get an adjunction since you don't have a representing object for each $C$.  If you did though, you'd immediately have the adjunction with no further work.